# Gaps between successive floating point numbers

Tags: numerical-methods, floating-point

(all numbers discussed are in decimal)

lets say we have a floating point data type that is like :

> m * 10 ^ e

```
where m is the mantissa . and max mantissa size is 1 ( 0 <= m <= 9);

e is the exponent and its size is  -1 <= e <= 1
```

we say our data type Max value is 90 and its Min value is 0

BUT : that does not mean we can represent all numbers that are in this limit .
we can only represent 27 numbers ( 9 * 3 ) excluding zero.

specifically we can't represent 89 in this way since it has a two digit mantissa 
(and non of them are zero).

so technically analogous to the above descriptions . in a float data type (in any programming language) there must be some integers between Max and Min values that we cannot store in a float data type .

is the above argument sound . if it is please give an example how to show this in java or c ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. For one thing, there are numbers that cannot be represented with a finite length. One of the most notable is $1/10$. In a binary representation, this is the repeating, non-terminating decimal $0.0\overline{0011}$.

Also, for a given precision (Let's say $24$, since that is that precision of 32-bit IEEE-$754$ floating point numbers, like the `float` type of Java or C), there are that many *binary* significant digits, which means that as the numbers get larger, the space between them increases as well. With $24$ significant digits in binary, the space between consecutive numbers is $2^{e-24}$, where $e$ is the exponent factor. A signed $32$-bit number can be as large as $2^{31}=2147483648$. At this point, the number is $2^{31-24}=2^8=128$ away from the previous number. That means anything between $2147483520$ and $2147483648$ cannot be accurately represented by a `float`, and will be rounded to one of those values.

Comment: also the smallest number that cannot be demonstrated is
$2^{24}+1$
since its binary is $1000000000000000000000001$ which has one bit more than 24 bits and the extra bit cannot be expressed in the exponent